# AES encryption for SagePay v3

Tags: php, encryption, aes, opayo

I am trying to upgrade my old SagePay pages from v2.22 to 3.00, however I am getting nowhere slowly with the AES encryption. The shopping cart and checkout pages are all prepared with the deprecated 2.22 and new 3.00 required fields, but I just cannot get to grips with the AES encryption. I have looked at, and played with, some of the example solutions posted here but with no joy. I have spoken to SagePay support services, but again no joy.

In a nutshell, all I want to do is to replace the old functionality previously contained in 'functions.php' with the new standard.

Comment: If you post your code, I'll help you out with the solution.....

Comment: Thanks Rik. Which bits of code would you like me to post? There is quite a bit throughout the four working pages.

Comment: If you have stuff which specifically relates to the encoding / encryption (and decoding) that will be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your functions / includes file:

```
function addPKCS5Padding($input)
{
     $blockSize = 16;
     $padd = "";
     $length = $blockSize - (strlen($input) % $blockSize);
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
{
     $padd .= chr($length);
}
     return $input . $padd;
}

function removePKCS5Padding($input)
{
    $blockSize = 16;
    $padChar = ord($input[strlen($input) - 1]);
    $unpadded = substr($input, 0, (-1) * $padChar);
    return $unpadded;
}


function encryptAes($string, $key)
{
    $string = addPKCS5Padding($string);
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
    return  strtoupper(bin2hex($crypt));
}


function decryptAes($strIn, $myEncryptionPassword)
{

#Sagepay specific - remove the '@'
$strIn = substr($strIn,1);

    $strInitVector = $myEncryptionPassword;
    $strIn = pack('H*', $hex);
    $string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $myEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$strInitVector);
    return removePKCS5Padding($string);
}
```

And I'll wait for your follow up, then show you what to change...